# Populating an Extjs graph with json not working

Tags: php, json, extjs, graph, store

So What I'm trying to do is populate an Extjs line graph. I've created a JSON store that pulls json from a remote page and for some reason my graph is not being populated.

Heres my Ext code:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoDestroy: true,
    url: 'http://myURL.com',
    storeId: 'graphStore',
    root: 'rows',
    idProperty: 'date',
    fields: ['date', 'posts']
});

new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Posts',
    renderTo: 'test_graph',
    width:500,
    height:300,
    layout:'fit',

    items: {
        xtype: 'linechart',
        store: store,
        xField: 'date',
        yField: 'posts',
        listeners: {
            itemclick: function(o){
                var rec = store.getAt(o.index);
                Ext.example.msg('Item Selected', 'You chose {0}.', rec.get('date'));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

});

And here's the JSON that is supposed to be populating it:

```
{"rows":[
    {"date":"2010-06-11","posts":4},
    {"date":"2010-06-12","posts":3},
    {"date":"2010-06-13","posts":1}, 
    {"date":"2010-06-14","posts":2}
]}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me why this won't work. The graph axis shows up, but the line doesn't render.

Comment: Hi,
I am facing the same problem. Did you figure out how to resolve it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem, even with `store.autoLoad` set to **true**

Actually, everything worked great when I hardcoded the json results into the page. But when I tried to use ajax to pull it from a database, the line never rendered! This wasn't a problem reading from the database, either. I verified that it was definitely pulling from the database.

I solved this by setting `autoLoad` to **false** and added `store.load()` after actual chart rendered and it worked totally fine.

Comment: +1 for personal story and your own fix. Thanks for taking the time to write the answer!

Answer (score 1):

you may want to set the autoLoad property to true on the store, such as:

```
var logsRemoteJsonStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore
({
    proxy: logsRemoteProxy
  , storeId: 'ourRemoteStore'
  , autoLoad: true
  , fields: logsRecordFields

});
```

In fact, verified that the following code from http://joefreeman.co.uk/projects/extstock/part-2.html does work, so it is almost certainly the autoload parameter, but review the other parameters in the example below.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        baseParams: {
            symbol: 'GOOG'
        },
        autoLoad: true,
        url: '/CMSAdmin/ReadSiteStatisticsEightMonthSummary/',
        root: 'data',
        fields: ['date', 'close']
    });

    new Ext.Window({
        title: 'GOOG',
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        items: new Ext.chart.LineChart({
            store: store,
            xField: 'date',
            yField: 'close'
        })
    }).show();

});
```

json:

```
{
  "symbol": "GOOG",
  "start": 1279627043,
  "span": 32140800,
  "data": [{
    "close": 462,
    "date": "2010-08-20"
  }, {
    "close": 476,
    "date": "2010-09-09"
  }, {
    "close": 527,
    "date": "2010-09-28"
  }, {
    "close": 601,
    "date": "2010-10-15"
  }, {
    "close": 620,
    "date": "2010-11-03"
  }, {
    "close": 591,
    "date": "2010-11-22"
  }, {
    "close": 592,
    "date": "2010-12-10"
  }, {
    "close": 598,
    "date": "2010-12-30"
  }, {
    "close": 631,
    "date": "2011-01-19"
  }]
}
```